# Is a redirect guaranteed to be delayed until all servlet filters have been processed?

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, weblogic, servlet-filters

I have a Java web application with two servlets. One servlet is used to create a new user account, the other one is used to edit an existing user account (given its unique id).

If servlet 1 is called ("/create-user"), it generates a new user account with a unique id and then issues a redirect to servlet 2: "/edit-user?uid=123". Servlet 2 then loads the data for the given user account.

Now the special thing:
All operations executed by the two servlets are performed in a kind of transaction. The transaction is started and finally committed by a servlet filter (pseudo code):

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Transaction t = Transaction.startTransaction();
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        t.commit();
    }
}
```

The user account generated by servlet 1 is not visible to the outside world (and therefore servlet 2) until the transaction has been committed.

This works perfect on 100+ installations based on various versions of Tomcat, WebSphere and JBoss. But there is one installation based on WebLogic 10.3.5.0 where we get an exception in servlet 2 because it is not able to find the user account. It seems as if the redirect instruction is sent back to the client and that the client sends it to the server BEFORE the original request is post-processed by the servlet filter. As a result, the new user account has not been committed yet and servlet 2 fails to load its data.

I know that a redirect is implemented as "Location" HTTP response header. I also know that a web server may start to send back data to the client (starting with the response header) before the complete response has been generated on server side. But is a client allowed to follow the redirect before the original HTTP request has been processed completely? Is there no guarantee that the original request has been fully processed (including all servlet filters) before the redirect takes place?

Comment: How would the client know that the request hasn't been fully processed? All it knows is that it has received a complete HTTP response. What the server does after having sent all the bytes of the response is none of the browser business, and not even possible to know. To me, your architecture is broken. The transaction should be committed *before* sending a response to the client.

Comment: I agree. Another option beside changing the architecture is maybe to use a response wrapper to buffer the output and pass it to the original response object after commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a servlet filter to handle user transactions. It must be done around the servlet. What if transaction fails? You dont have way to send an error page, because the HTTP response could be already commited.

In your case, the http response is probably already sent to the client before your filter has made commit.

I would recommend to refactor your code to set a transactional aspect into your servlet and your problem would surely dissapear.